# Why is submit button over top of textarea field?

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://dev.blendbee.com/shop/subscriptions/tea-of-the-month-club/):

I can't figure out how to haxxor the CSS so that the green "Sign Up Now" button isn't over top of the textarea field.  I want it to display BELOW the input field.

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's weird that this is even happening, since this is a paid WordPress theme.

Comment: Check your html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the css file(woocommerce.css) find this class and add it a margin-top:

```
.button, a.button.checkout {
  background: #6cbe42;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't do it exactly like that, but your answer definitely led me down the right path - thanks!

Comment: The problem is the height of the p. see my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `height` set to the container `p.form-row-wide` of the `textarea`. Chrome print it visually correctly, but the CSS code makes this result:

[image]

So the button 'Sign Up' in your browser overlap the textarea.
To fix it, update your CSS:

```
.woocommerce form .form-row-wide, 
.woocommerce-page form .form-row-wide {
   clear: both;
   height: auto;
}
```